# MySQL datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-formatting

I am creating a registration page in HTML, PHP, and MySQL. I want to add a hidden field in the registration to be used as join date.

Is it better to have the hidden field containing the current date and time or assigning a variable the current datetime and using that in the SQL insert statement instead?

Anyways, if the following hidden form field is used, what would the date format be to store the datetime as `2010-07-06 07:55:12`?

```
<input name="joindate" type="hidden" id="joindate"  value="<?php echo date(''); ?>">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
 echo date('Y-m-d g:i:s',time()); //PHP
```

Our Better MySQL use `datetime` filed and call `NOW()

```
 INSERT INTO registration (Name,Date) VALUES ('Jarlsberg Cheese',NOW()) ;
```

In your SQL Statements

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks m8, ill be using the now()

Comment: If you want to store in the `UTC` timezone use `UTC_TIMESTAMP` instead of `NOW()`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a hidden field, assign a variable to the current date/time (or use the NOW() function in MySQL) and use that as the join date.

The reason being that someone could easily use a tool like Firebug to edit that hidden join date field and put a value you didn't intend into your database.

Answer (score 2):

You can even do it in SQL: insert into user (...,joindate) values (...,NOW());

That way you don't have to fiddle with formatting..

Edit: But if you don't like this, there is no point in passing this value to the client and back. Just set it when you create your insert query. Using the hidden field you are risking that someone actually changes your value and sets it to something unexpected..

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.. So yes! :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

The date format that you have mentioned is a valid MySQL datetime. In PHP you can echo it like this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Or, with your example:

```
<input name="joindate" type="hidden" id="joindate"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

In line with Eric Petroelje:

Create a field with the Type `timestamp` and set as Default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Then you don't even have to mention this field in your insert-statement. It just inserts the time and date of the insert.

Simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a column in your database table either with TIMESTAMP, DATETIME or even VARCHAR datatypes and insert into it the date and time using the now() function. It works just fine. Goodluck!!!

INSERT INTO table_name(Some_column,Date_column) VALUES ('Ephraim Tarfa',now()) ;